# $(document).on - Must click page once before it works with draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jQuery draggable UI and it works as intended. However I'm using an AJAX call to empty the container div and append new draggable div's.

Instead of using `$('.draggableselector').draggable({});` 
I'm using `$(document).on('click', '.draggableselector' function () { });`

Bu the result of this is that I must click the document once before draggable works.

Is there a way I can re-add the listener at the same time as the `.append()`, so this extra click isn't needed?

```
//New
$(document).on('click', '.plrobj', function() {
    $( ".plrobj" ).draggable({

        stack: ".plrobj",
        distance: 0,
        revert: "invalid", 
        opacity: 0.5, 
        helper: "clone" 
    });
});

//Original
$(function() {
    $( ".plrobj" ).draggable({

        stack: ".plrobj",
        distance: 0,
        revert: "invalid", 
        opacity: 0.5, 
        helper: "clone" 
    });
});
```

**$.post** :

```
$( function() {
    $(".Selection").click(function(){
        var SelectedVar = $(this).attr('value');

        function Update() {
                var Formation = SelectedVar;
                $.post("PitchExternalProcessing.php", { data: $('Form').serialize()},
                        function (result) {
                        var returnedHTML = JSON.parse(result);
                        $(".mainbox > .childbox").empty();
                        $(".mainbox").append(returnedHTML[0]);
                        $(".siblingbox").empty();
                        $(".siblingbox").append(returnedHTML[1]);
                        }
                );
        }
        Update();
    });
```

**NOTE:**
I've removed a large chunk of the code including the `droppable` elements for simplicity but I tested it beforehand and it still had the same resulting action.

Comment: Put the logic in a function and call that onload of the page and the click of the `.plrobj` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
//Original
$(function() {
  function initDraggables($elements){
    $elements.draggable({
        stack: ".plrobj",
        distance: 0,
        revert: "invalid", 
        opacity: 0.5, 
        helper: "clone" 
    });
  }
 initDraggables( $(".plrobj") );
});
```

When your ajax call finish, invoke `initDraggables()` and pass the newly created elements to it. This will avoid reinitializing on the elements that are already draggable

Comment: If this is a silly question apologies, but I'm trying to verbalise it so I understand it. 1) on Intial page load `initDraggables( $(".plrobj") );` added the listener to the draggable objects `.plrobj`. So 2) after each ajax call, call the function and it will re-add the listener?